# Converting nested null values to empty strings inside dataframe spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, null, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I am looking to convert null values nested in Array of String to empty strings in spark. The data is in a dataframe. I plan on running a reduce function after making the dataframe null safe, not sure if that helps in answering the question. I am using spark 1.6.

Schema:

```
root
|-- carLineName: array (nullable = true)
|    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

Example input:

```
+--------------------+
|carLineName         |
+--------------------+
|[null,null,null]    |
|[null, null]        |
|[Mustang, null]     |
|[Pilot, Jeep]       |
```

Desired output:

```
+--------------------+
|carLineName         |
+--------------------+
|[,,]                | 
|[,]                 |
|[Mustang,]          |
|[Pilot, Jeep]       |
```

My attempt:

```
val safeString: Seq[String] => Seq[String] = s => if (s == null) "" else s
val udfSafeString = udf(safeString)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The input to the `UDF` is a sequence of strings, not a single string. Since that is the case, you need to `map` over it. You can do this as follows:

```
val udfSafeString = udf((arr: Seq[String]) => {
  arr.map(s => if (s == null) "" else s)
})

df.withColumn("carLineName", udfSafeString($"carLineName"))
```